# Azure Billing API returning 404 Error, any Ideas?

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, billing

### 404 Error

Good afternoon,
i want to use the Billing API to get Information About my Costs...
I tried to run the sample from GitHub https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-usage-api.

I did all steps which are described in the read me but i get a 404 Error when i call it.
I checked already if there is a typo in the Subscription ID but it is not.

Thank you David